# In Laravel, running "php artisan" returns "Server responsed with code 404"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, bitnami

I'm trying to get my Laravel project, checked out of git, working on Windows with Bitnami Wampstack 7.1.16 (php 7.1). I'm running:

```
php ../php/composer.phar install
```

which installs many dependencies but also has an error:

```
> @php artisan package:discover
Server responsed with code 404
```

I can run php artisan, which produces the same error. (If I don't have an .env file it errors out with code 0) I've tried updating composer (to 1.6.3) but it doesn't seem to help. Apache loads the web pages fine, so it's just the command line that is causing difficulty.

Any ideas how to revive php artisan? How does artisan connect to the server in the first place? I'm suspecting something unusual in Bitnami...

Comment: Try running the command with the verbose option to get a call stack of what is going on and supply the output in your question. `php artisan package:discover -vvv`

Comment: @domdambrogia Strangely this didn't come up with any further information.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you start a new project targeting the version you checked out of git and copying the needful into the new projects.

Replace 5.3.* with the version from git

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.3.*"
```

Comment: Thanks that got me started on debugging.

Comment: This is a poor answer. He's looking for info on how to debug his problem and why it is happening. Wiping everything the OP has done and _starting over_ isn't helpful information to explain what the OP is doing wrong and how to fix it for the future. It's a poor work around.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to debug this enough to find the problem was in my own custom commands. I had called the exit(-1) function when an error occurred, so Laravel didn't give me help in finding the error.

In summary: don't call exit() when throwing an exception would be better!